# Unable to take inverse cdf for a non uniform discrete variable

Tags: python, scipy, inverse, cdf

This is my code:

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
xk = (30, 20, 50)
pk = (0.30, 0.2, 0.5)
custm = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(xk, pk))
X = np.random.random((100,3))

## Map back into the specified distribution by inverting the CDF
X[:, 0] = st.norm.ppf(X[:, 0], 5,2)
X[:, 1] = st.lognorm.ppf(X[:, 1], 6,1)
##This following line does not work
X[:, 2] = st.rv_discrete.ppf(X[:, 2], values=(xk, pk))
```

When I run the code above, I get this error:

```
TypeError: ppf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to call .ppf on an *instance*, i.e. `custm.ppf` in your example.